# Significance of 64 in x86-64

Tags: operating-system, cpu, processor, cpu-registers

I know that `x86` means a `32 bit CPU`(or data and address buses are capable of carrying `32 bits`)  and I also have found it being mentioned as `x86-64`. What does the `64` mean in the `x86-64`? What about the `registers`?

Also correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: x86-64 is just the 64-bit version of the x86 instruction set. And it has more and bigger registers...

Comment: x86 started as 16 bit architecture, or perhaps less...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x86 refers to the instruction set that is compatible with the old school Intel 8086 CPU.  So it's referring to the instruction set, not whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit.  See the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86).

The x86_64 is a chip that is compatible with that instruction set, but supports 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

x86_64 bit means the resource you are looking at is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

for more information, see [easy x86-64](http://ianseyler.github.com/easy_x86-64/)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also [per the faq's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) you must disclose your affiliation *within* the answer.